# `Ole2.h` include causing an error

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-c++-2012

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2012. I have the following as part of my header setup:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Ole2.h>
```

When I include `windows.h` on it's own there's no build errors, but when I include `Ole2.h` either with `windows.h` or without `windows.h` I get the following compiler error:

```
Error   1   error C2628: '_RPC_ASYNC_NOTIFICATION_INFO::$UnnamedClass$0x1c06c483$29$' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\rpcasync.h   127 1   Test`
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong? Ultimately I'm trying to write some simple code to interface with Kinect, but even without any Kinect includes present the above error is still generated.

When I double click the error I am taken to `rpcasync.h` and the following code:

```
#if !defined(RPC_NO_WINDOWS_H)
//
// Notification by window message
//
struct {
    HWND hWnd;
    UINT Msg;
    } HWND;     //<<<-------- the error points here (HWND is underlined in red)

#endif // RPC_NO_WINDOWS_H
```

PS The reason I'm including `Ole2.h` at all is because I'm following [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~edwardz/tutorials/kinect/kinect1.html) tutorial.

Comment: What if you define RPC_NO_WINDOWS_H ?

Comment: Interesting - `windows.h` usually includes `ole2.h` itself.  Try setting the `C/C++ | Advanced | Show Includes` project setting to yes and see where it's getting the header files from.  For me both `windows.h` and `ole2.h` come from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`.  Lookout for any header that doesn't come from `Windows Kits\8.0` or `Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC` (or wherever Express puts the VC headers).

Comment: @user2120666 that solution worked !

Comment: @Michael Burr: windows.h only include ole2.h only if you define INC_OLE2.

Comment: @Xearinox: it's being included in my test without `INC_OLE2` being defined.  Looking at `windows.h`, it seems that `ole2.h` is included if either `NOGDI` is undefined or `INC_OLE2` is defined.

Comment: @pbs: the intent for defining `RPC_NO_WINDOWS_H` is to let you include `rpc.h` without having it pulling in `windows.h`.  You shouldn't have to define that macro to get your example to work - you have some other issue that you should get to the root of or I expect that you'll run into to other problems.

Comment: @Michael yes I thought this myself. Thanks - I will keep this in mind!

Comment: @Michael Burr: Interesting, in my project is included only if I define INC_OLE2. But your comments to the problems are accurate. Respect.

Comment: Add `-lole32` flag to your linker, try that.